# ¿Como pasar un valor fecha a un input de tipo date, en Grails 3.8?

Tags: html, grails

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con grails 3.8, tengo guardada una fecha en BD y quiero que se muestre en un input de tipo date, solo que si le paso el valor tal y como viene  de la BD me muestra un error por el formato con el se extrae lo estoy pasando de la siguiente manera

```
<div class="col-sm-4 cedula">
   <label for="" class="control-label">Fecha asignación de Grado</label>
      <input type="date" value="${detalleTesis?.asignacionGrado}" class="form-control" name="asignacionGrado" required="true">
 </div>
```

Comment: Debes enviar la fecha con formato

Answer (score 1):

Cuando yo necesito mostrar una fecha en una view, siempre utilizo el tag de Grails: g:formatDate.

Lo que hace el tag es formatear el objecto *java.util.Date* a tu gusto.

Un ejemplo en tu caso podria ser este:

```
<g:formatDate format="dd/MM/yyyy" date="${detalleTesis?.asignacionGrado}" class="form-control" name="asignacionGrado" required="true"/>
```